# Which SQL Join do I use to see results from one table that are not present in set from the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a massive table wherein records are generated each month, and the results tagged with `month_of` column.  I need to compare these `month_of` result sets each month to find new activations (new records that are present this month that weren't there last month)

The goal:
Get a set of results from the CURRENT MONTH where in the unique-ids are not present in the PREVIOUS MONTH.

Explained:

Last month (March), I had 10 records marked status="ACTIVE" with month_of "MARCH"

This month (April), I have 11 records marked status="ACTIVE" with month_of "APRIL"

Something like this I've already tried:
if ta1 = current months's report, and ta2 = last month's report

```
SELECT id FROM table ta1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table ta2
ON ta1.status = ta2.status
WHERE ta1.month_of = #{current_month}
AND ta2.month_of = #{last_month}
AND ta1.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND ta2.id IS null
```

I need the query that would return the 1 new record with month_of "APRIL" that isn't present in the month_of "MARCH" results.

Can anyone point me at the right join to use in order to get what I'm looking for?  This solution is going to apply to a table with almost a billion records.

Comment: Can you create an actual example of the table data and relations and the desired output? What you want is most likely two INNER JOINS but I don't get the `ON ta1.status = ta2.status` part.

Comment: If your `id` is unique why not use `IN` query as `select ta1.id from ta1 where ta1.id not in (select id from ta2);`

Comment: Hey @max; the status column can be either "ACTIVE" or "INACTIVE", and the idea is I want to find all the like statuses from this month's report and last month's report.

I ended up doing a left join.  I updated my original post with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS ARTICLE](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) was immensely helpful in my understanding of joins and how to use them.

I actually ended up using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT se1.id FROM service_effectivenesses se1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN service_effectivenesses se2
        ON se1.vehicle_id = se2.vehicle_id
        AND se1.dealership_id = se2.dealership_id
        WHERE se1.dealership_id = #{dealershio_id}
        AND se2.id IS NULL
        AND se1.month_of = DATE('#{month_of.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}')
        AND se2.month_of = DATE('#{month_of.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}') - interval '1 month'
        AND se1.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

The `#{}` variables are from our Rails app, so ignore those.

Answer (score 1):

select id
from ta1
where month_of = (current_month)
    and id not in (select id from ta1 where month_of = (last_month))
    and status in ('Active')

or you could do:

select a.id
from(select id, month_of from ta1 where month_of = (current_month) and status = 'Active'
)a
left join (select id, month_of from ta1 where month_of = (last_month)
)b on a.id != b.id